# Is the von neumann algebra of locally compact amenable group hyperfinite?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, amenability

Let $G$ be a discrete group and $\mathcal{L}(G)$ the associated von Neumann algebra. It is well known that $G$ is amenable if and only if $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is hyperfinite.

Does there exist a generalization of this theorem to arbitrary locally compact groups?

Answer (score 3):

A. Connes result from 1976 is that if $G$ is separable and locally compact and $G/G_0$ is amenable, where $G_0$ is the connected component of the identity, then $\mathcal L(G)$ is approximately finite-dimensional. In particular, this occurs when $G$ is solvable separable locally compact, and when $G$ is connected separable locally compact.

There might be newer results, since a lot of work has been done on group von Neumann algebras since then.

Comment: Are you sure that Connes was dealing with separable (rather than second-countable) groups?

Comment: I copied that statement almost verbatim from his paper; he definitely uses the word "separable". Like I said, I don't know about newer stuff.

Comment: That's surprising (probably he had made a mistake) because if you take a separable but non-second-countable group like $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ then there is a problem with the definition of hyperfiniteness (the usual conditions that we use for separably acting von Neumann algebras are no longer equivalent).